# MOC adding namespace to class names

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, moc

I have this very strange problem while compiling the project. 
MOC seems to be adding a namespace to the class name being moc'ed, although it's not mentioned anywhere in the file/class.

The namespace, however, exists in a library which I use, but it's hidden far away in the header files and I don't use it in the UI files. This is what MOC generates:

```
const QMetaObject SmpTl::CaptureController::staticMetaObject = {
{ &QObject::staticMetaObject, qt_meta_stringdata_SmpTl__CaptureController,
  qt_meta_data_SmpTl__CaptureController, 0 }};
```

The `SmpTl` namespace is not mentioned anywhere in the declaration of `CaptureController`, but it appears in the MOC-generated .cpp file.

I'm using Visual Studio with the QT integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SmpTl` is the namespace `CaptureController` is defined in, as it was found by MOC.

The `Q_OBJECT` macro expands into the declaration of the `staticMetaObject`-variable inside your class definition (among other things it expands into). The MOC-file contains the definition of that variable.

If this is not correct, please post your Qt version and a stripped down version of your header-file.

Comment: I found the problem, it was a missing '"' in the asm code of some header file far away in the include list. The code was #ifdef'ed only for MIPS architecture, so the compiler didn't complain about the missing ", but somehow MOC got confused.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this problem. I had code that looked like this:

```
namespace foo {
    #ifdef _WIN32
    ...   // This code was fine
    #else
    #error Not Supported
    #endif
}
```

This confused MOC into thinking namespace `foo` never closed. Apparently, it didn't know `_WIN32` was defined, and got tripped up by the fact that I forgot to put quotes around the error message. Changing it to:

```
#error "Not Supported"
```

fixed my problem.

Comment: Ran across the exact same problem, Thanks! I have to add it only happened if the #error line contained the single quotation `'` character. Removing the `'` or enclosing the error string in double quotations `"` fixed the issue for me.