# C++: Qt moc does not understand quote separator between digits

Tags: qt, c++14, moc

In C++14, quotes are introduced as [digit separator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). But Qt MOC interprets those quotes wrongly. Here is an code fragment which explains the problem:

```
enum Access : int32_t
{
    GRANTED = 0b0000'0001,
    DENIED  = 0b0000'0011
};
```

If MOC runs on this code fragment, it causes the errors described in [MOC adding namespace to class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684508/moc-adding-namespace-to-class-names). The moc version is 5.9.0. Does this issue is fixed in newer Qt versions?

Comment: Please post exactly what your problem is inside your question, including the wrong output relevant to your code sample. The other question you linked is 8 years old, a lot of has changed in moc since then. Anyway, moc doesn't need to know  about such enum, so you could put it inside `#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN` block... Not the best solution, but it should work.

Comment: According to [this changeset](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/187820/) it has been fixed in the 5.9 branch already.